# If $N$ and $M/N$ satisfy ACC condition, can $M$ also satisfy it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $N$ be a submodule of $R$-module $M$. If $N$ and $M/N$ satisfy ACC condition, can $M$ also satisfy it?

Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take a chain in $M$, look at what happens after it's image in $M/N$ and intersection with $N$ both stabilize.

Comment: What does the ascending chain of $M$ look like (in tern of the ascending chains of $M/N$ and $N$)?

Comment: May you make your hint more precise?

Comment: Here's one more hint, and the last one that I'll give:  Prove the following statement.  *Let $\phi\colon M \to M/N$ be the quotient map.  If $A \subseteq B \subseteq M$ are submodules such that $\phi(A) = \phi(B)$ and $A \cap N = B \cap N$ then $A = B$.*